# Why Javascript event being fired on pageload when I specify for change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ddl and am trying to use jquery to execute an event when selected option is change but the function for the change event is being executed when the page loads.

```
$(function () {
$("#<%= ddlMake.ClientID %>").change(handleddl1());});
```

Does it matter if it is a asp ddl being populated by sql datasource?

Any explanation as to why and how I could make it work as needed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're *calling* `handleddl1` instead of just *passing* it. Use this instead:

```
$(function () {
    $("#<%= ddlMake.ClientID %>").change(handleddl1);
});
```

Comment: you're on fire this morning :-)

Comment: I put an alert statement in the "handleddl1" function to see when it's executed. With the code to that Joseph suggest, when I change the selection on the ddl there was no alert.